# Какие данные можно получить с сервера по протоколу icmp?

Tags: безопасность, firewall, icmp

Допустим я хочу ограничить доступ к серверу и блокирую `tcp:80` и `tcp:443`, но при этом оставляю открытым `icmp`.

Comment: Или вам ограничили доступ на 80 и 443, оставив открытым icpm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужен [ICMP-туннель](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICMP-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C). Да, про него даже статья в Википедии есть.

В большинстве дистрибутивов из коробки есть [утилита ptunnel, которая делает ровно это](http://www.mit.edu/afs.new/sipb/user/golem/tmp/ptunnel-0.61.orig/web/). Завернуть таким образом в ICMP можно любые TCP соединения, только лишь не стоит рассчитывать на высокие скорости. Есть [порт под Android](https://github.com/f1vefour/ptunnel).

Comment: Я так и знал что есть что то подобное.